# "ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView Selection.Range, True" does not work

Tags: vba, scroll, view, ms-word

I need VBA (Word) to scroll to a certain location in the document before a messagebox (`msgbox`) in the macro is displayed.

I have tried:

- `ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView Selection.Range, True`
- I have added `DoEvents` before the `Msgbox` call. Didn't work.
- I have added a bookmark and then selected the bookmark before the `Msgbox`
- I have added a sleeptimer, and other delays, before the `Msgbox`. Didn't work.
- I have tried `Application.Screenrefresh`

Nothing works. `Msgbox` always displays with the cursor in the location it was located before the macro ran.

HOWEVER, if I step through the code in the VBA editor, all works fine. It's only when I am running the code 'straight through' that it never observes the ScrollIntoView command before showing the msgbox.

(Start at top of document)
(Search for text on, let's say page 3; if found . . .)

```
ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView Selection.Range, True
DoEvents
Application.ScreenRefresh
Selection.Bookmarks.Add "Prompt"
Selection.Bookmarks("Prompt").Select
DoEvents
Selection.Range.Select
MsgBox "    TASK:  " & PromptIs & String(2, 13) & "    Click OK below and perform the stated task."
```

The cursor should be at the found text and the text should be 'in view' before the message box is displayed. It's not.

Comment: Works for me with only `ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView Selection.Range, True`  The messagebox displays after the selected range is shown.

Comment: please provide the *entire* code context ([mcve]) including what is selected before the code is run, what the "find" code looks like that is mentioned in the question, etc. Also, check whether `ScreenUpdating` is turned on or off and make sure it's on.

Comment: Cindy, Aaarrrggghhhh. Prior to this code block, I guess I had turned `ScreenUpdating` to False. Set it to True, plus a `ScreenRefresh`. All 100%. Thanks! (And thanks to Scott of editing the original Q.)  (I don't see how to mark your comment as the answer and add 'stars'. Add 10,000 stars!)